# What do I need to use a Metz 54 MZ-4 remotely with a Canon Rebel T2i?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, flash, off-camera-flash, metz

I believe that the Metz 54 doesn't have a PC cable, and I'm looking for the cheapest option. The T2i doesn't have this built in does it?

Answer (score 1):

The Metz 54 MZ-4 uses the "[SCA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Camera_Adaption)" module system — there's swappable bases which you change depending on camera system. For Canon, you probably have the [SCA 3102 dedicated TTL module](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/217270-REG/Metz_MZ_53102_SCA_3102_Dedicated_Module.html).

What you need, though, is the simple [**SCA 301 standard ISO foot**](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/35054-REG/Metz_MZ_5519_SCA_301_Standard_Flash.html), which has a sync port. This costs about $12.50, and you use it in combination with [this cable or similar](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/35081-REG/Metz_MZ_5548_36_50_PC_Male_to.html), which is PC male to 2.5mm sub-mini.

With this approach, you'd still need [an adapter with a PC sync port](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/764579-REG/Nisha_HTS_P_Professional_Mult_Purpose_Hot_Shoe.html) on the camera's hotshoe, as none of the Canon Rebel line has PC sync ports. (There goes another $12.)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's some information](http://pixsylated.com/blog/canon-speedlites-optical-slaves/) regarding optical slaves from Syl Arena.

Comment: +1, optical slaves are a moderately flexible, very affordable solution for a flash with a standard hotshoe that uses the central pin to fire.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what connectors the Mets 54 has, but there are some options that will work with any flash:

1. You can get a cable that connects to your camera's hotshoe on one side and has an hotshoe-like connector on the other side, something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HOT-SHOE-CABLE-CORD-CANON-SPEEDLITE-FLASH-430EX-580EX-320EX-270EX-II-/130594098367?pt=Camera_Flash_Accessories&hash=item1e6803ccbf)
2. You can get cheap radio triggers with hotshoe connectors, for example [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/iShoot-Radio-Flash-Trigger-Camera-Remote-Control-PT-04-G-Canon-Nikon-Pentax-/250915305439?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a6bb7b7df)

Both products I linked to are meant as an example, they are just the first options that came up in an eBay search, I don't own and never used any of them (but I have used similar radio triggers with my T2i and a flash with no PC sync post).